# How to use front camera for barcode scanning in ipod

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, ipod, barcode-scanner

I am using back camera to read bar code data...and it is scanning perfectly.Now I want to use front camera for this...How can I do this? Where should I make change?I have used ZBar bar code reader

my code is:

```
   - (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
          {
         // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
            ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
            reader.readerDelegate = self;
             reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

              ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
           // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

          // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
               [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];

          // present and release the controller
               [self presentModalViewController: reader
                         animated: YES];
               [reader release];
    }

        - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
            { 
              // ADD: get the decode results
                 id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
                   [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
                   ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
                   for(symbol in results)
                       // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
                          break;

                       // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
                          resultText.text = symbol.data;
                          bid.text=symbol.data;

                       // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
                          resultImage.image =
                          [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

                       // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
                          [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
                     }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you have to do is open your Camera to be in Front Mode instead of Rear Mode, so write this inside the method where you call the picker for the first time:

```
  picker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

Hope this answers your question. If not, tell me.

Comment: Is this working reliably? The front camera doesn't support auto focus, thats why I was asking. I'm using the built-in ios support using [AVCaptureMetadataOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureMetadataOutput/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureMetadataOutput) for scanning bar codes and i find the front camera is not very reliable.